# 2x2 Matrices that are not valid quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, bloch-sphere

Given a 2-dimensional Hilbert space, quantum states can be expressed as $2\times 2$ density matrices. In terms of the Pauli matrices, or Bloch representation, they can be written as
\begin{equation}
\rho=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbb{I}+\vec{r}\cdot\vec{\sigma}\right)
\end{equation}
where $\vec{r}$ is the Bloch vector in the Bloch sphere and $|\vec{r}|\leq1$.

QUESTION 1: Are there $2\times 2$ matrices that are not valid quantum states?

QUESTION 2: Are there singular $2\times 2$ matrices that are valid quantum states?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes. Not all $2 \times 2$ matrices have trace 1, but all density matrices do. There are also lots of other special properties of density matrices, like being Hermitian.
2. Yes. For example, consider a pure state $\rho = | \psi \rangle \langle \psi |$. This is a rank 1 matrix, because it's just projection onto $|\psi \rangle$, so it is not invertible.

Comment: How about mixed states? Are there singular $2\times 2$ matrices that are valid mixed states?

Comment: @Janus. There are no 2 by 2 singular mixed states, but this is a special case for a two-dimensional system. (You can see this by diagonalizing the density matrix and noting that for a mixed state, there must be at least two non-zero eigenvalues.)

Comment: @march Thanks. So, say I have a random $2\times 2$ nonsingular positive definite matrix with trace 1, am I assured that it is a valid quantum state? Also, are you saying that for higher dimensional systems, there are $n\times n$ singular matrices with trace 1 that are valid quantum states?

Comment: @Janus. Yes to both of your questions. If you want details, you'll probably want to ask a new question.

Comment: Try the book "Geometry of quantum states"